# Euler Characteristic for Convex Polyhedra

Tags: geometry

It is well-known that a convex polyhedron with $V$ vertices, $E$ edges, and $F$ faces has Euler characteristic $2$: $V-E+F=2$.

Conversely, given a triple $(V,E,F)$ satisfying the above relation, can we always construct a covex polyhedron with $V$ vertices $E$ edges, and $F$ faces?

Comment: In short, no. There are only 5 so-called *Platonic Solids*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid might be of interest.

Comment: You could hardly have $2$ vertices, $1$ edge and $1$ face; however, the question of which $(V,E,F)$ can be realized seems interesting.

Comment: Are you saying that there are only 5 convex polyhedra @dleggas ?  I don't think the O.P. was asking about necessarily regular polyhedra.

Comment: dleggas is clearly misunderstanding the question. And Peter Franek that is really my question I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every convex polyhedron in $3$ space corresponds to a $3$ regular planar graph. For example, a cube corresponds to the peterson graph $P(4,1)$. This is called **Steinitz's Theorem.** Therefore, to see that if we can construct a convex polyhedron with certain $V,F,E$, we only need to create a $3$ regular planar graph with the same $V,E,$ and $F$.

An interesting application is that we can prove that there are an infinite convex polyhedra with only hexagon and pentagonal faces. They correspond to **Fullerene Graphs**. We can then use  some basic theorems in graph theory to prove that such a convex polyhedra MUST have only $12$ pentagonal faces.

Comment: The second part is unrelated. So how do we know if we can create a 3 regular planar graph with the same V,E,F?

Comment: Try to draw it... You can check some easy planarity conditions like $E < 3(V-2)$.